# How to change the "from" field in nodemailer?

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

*Disclaimer: I'm not very good with technical email aspects.*

So I've setup up a free [zoho mail](https://www.zoho.com/mail/) account which basically is just an mail server for my domain. This kinda works via mx record forwarding or something, I'm not entirely sure how it works.

Anyway, the point is: I can change easily the from field when using my account per Outlook. So my email address `foo@bar.com` appears as `Foo from bar.com` in most email clients.

Now I want to send some automated emails from my `donotreply@bar.com` account with nodemailer (v1.10.0) over SMTP with SSL. I've tried different approaches I've found in the documentation / on the internet. All of them just have thrown an ambigious stack trace (see below).

As soon as I stop trying to change the from field everything works fine (except for the *wrong* from field). Since I've no idea whats goin on I'm asking for some help troubleshooting this.

I've tried changing the second argument of `createTransport()` to my desired from field. Did not work.

```
nodemailer.createTransport(auth.mail, {from: auth.mail.auth.user});
```

to

```
nodemailer.createTransport(auth.mail, {from: 'Foo from bar.com'});
```

I've tried setting `auth.mail.from` which did also not work. And I've tried setting `auth.mail.from` with passing a 2nd parameter to `createTransport()`.

---

My code

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var auth = { mail: { host: 'smtp.zoho.com', port: 465, secure: true, auth: { user: 'donotreply@bar.com', pass: 'strongpassword' } };
var log = require('./log');

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(auth.mail, {from: auth.mail.auth.user});

function sendText(settings,cb) {
    transporter.sendMail(settings, function (err, info) {
        if (err) {
            log.warn('Failed to send an Email', err);
        } else {
            log.info('Successfully sent email', info);
        }
        if (cb) {
            cb(err, info);
        }
    });
}
```

---

Here the stacktrace I've talked about before

```
Message failed
    at SMTPConnection._formatError (c:\...\node_modules\nodemailer\node_modules\nodemailer-smtp-transport\node_modules\smtp-connection\src\smtp-connection.js:388:15)
    at SMTPConnection._actionStream (c:\...\node_modules\nodemailer\node_modules\nodemailer-smtp-transport\node_modules\smtp-connection\src\smtp-connection.js:948:30)
    at SMTPConnection.<anonymous> (c:\...\node_modules\nodemailer\node_modules\nodemailer-smtp-transport\node_modules\smtp-connection\src\smtp-connection.js:579:14)
    at SMTPConnection._processResponse (c:\...\node_modules\nodemailer\node_modules\nodemailer-smtp-transport\node_modules\smtp-connection\src\smtp-connection.js:511:16)
    at SMTPConnection._onData (c:\...\node_modules\nodemailer\node_modules\nodemailer-smtp-transport\node_modules\smtp-connection\src\smtp-connection.js:357:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:146:16)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:110:10)
    at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:523:20)
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The from field has to be in the the format `Display Name <email@address.com>`

```
transporter.sendMail({ ..., from: 'Foo from @bar.com <donotreply@bar.com>' });
```

Answer (score 16):

I had the same issue with the `from:` field and I went back to read gmail setup and this is what i found - as i said, only GMAIL. I haven't tried a different provider yet. 
src: [nodemailer.com/usage/using-gmail/](https://nodemailer.com/usage/using-gmail/)
Client: Gmail

> Gmail also always sets authenticated username as the From: email
>   address. So if you authenticate as foo@example.com and set
>   bar@example.com as the from: address, then Gmail reverts this and
>   replaces the sender with the authenticated user.

basically, you can only specify the authenticated user on the `from:` field

thank you, if I'm wrong, please let me know

Comment: Is there a way to overwrite this?

Comment: There is no way @JoelHarkes

Comment: Verified this today as well ^

Comment: At this date this is still not possible :(

Answer (score 9):

The first example that you can look on [nodemailer.com](http://nodemailer.com/) website.

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

// create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport('smtps://user%40gmail.com:pass@smtp.gmail.com');
/*set from user in option*/
var mailOptions = {
    from: 'Fred Foo  <foo@blurdybloop.com>', // sender address
    to: 'bar@blurdybloop.com, baz@blurdybloop.com', // list of receivers
    subject: 'Hello ✔', // Subject line
    text: 'Hello world ', // plaintext body
    html: '<b>Hello world </b>' // html body
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if(error){
        return console.log(error);
    }
    console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
});
```